# What is a person who gets pranked called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Someone who pranks someone else is called a prankster. What is a person who gets pranked called? Is the term "prank victim"?

Answer (score 18):

Depends on the point of view:

from the prankster the word "target" could be relevant

But, from a bystander the word "victim" would also work.

Comment: Given how most "pranks" seem to be not-very-well-disguised abuse, victim is absolutely the word that comes to mind.

Comment: @JKreft yes, gone from a simple harmless practical joke, some pranks are now downright vicious...

Comment: Target and victim are  general terms that can be used in different contexts. The OP is looking for words or expressions which clearly relates to pranks.

Comment: @user070221 that's the beauty of the language - the variety of words that can be used...

Answer (score 16):

You have ***[prankee](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/prankee):***

> The victim of a prank.
>
> - 2003, Tara Calishain, Rael Dornfest, Google hacks (page 271): 
>     *There are three ways to deliver the prank to the prankee. The first way is in person.* (Wiktionary)

But “prank victim” is more commonly used.

Comment: There is also _victim of the prank,_ which, interestingly enough, is the only one of the three to get a hit in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prankee%2Cprank+victim%2Cvictim+of+the+prank&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15).

Comment: @J.R. and  better, probably, [_victim of a prank_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prankee%2Cprank+victim%2Cvictim+of+the+prank%2Cvictim+of+a+prank&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Wow, yes, but that's a entirely different question – one that probably would merit the **[tag:articles]** tag!

Comment: This askee's answer seems to be what the askster was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The person who gets pranked can be called the **laughingstock** or the **butt of the joke**. In addition, there are many words for victims who are tricked by minor frauds, which can also be applied to prank victims: **sucker, dupe, mark, chump, sap, patsy**.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but nonetheless relevant: we can coin words *by analogy* and native speakers will understand them.

**Prankster** and **the prankified**.

We could even say

> Did I ever get pranked. I got totally prankified.

The coined past participle **prankified** creates *ad hoc* the transitive verb **to prankify** by analogy with other verbs ending in **-ify**.

Comment: Looks like there is a  ***http://www.prankified.com/***

Comment: I don't get the downvotes here. This seems like useful information for a learner.

Comment: It's the internet, @J.R.  :)